# Android: declaring particular activity as the launcher activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am just starting with android and trying to alter my android manifext .xml file such that a particular activity is launched first.  My code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".CrimeListActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".CrimeActivity">
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have a CrimeListActivity java class which simply should display an empty activity.  However, it continues to default to displaying the activity that was specified in the manifest originally.  ( In this case, .CrimeActivity.

It's hard to be more specific without posting too much code so I'm hoping someone could give me a couple pointers on where to start poking around when issues like this arise.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want CrimeActivity as launcher..?

Comment: You mean SplashScreen?

Comment: Are you sure this manifest is picked up for compilation - just introduce an error and see if it shouts !

Comment: Or make sure that CrimeListActivity and CrimeActivity doesn't have the same exact content/code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. Adimaano, you nailed it for me.  Thanks.  Two classes intended to do different things with the same code. Lol.  Much appreciated.